# How to Edit a cell in Flutter DataTable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a DataTable. It is constructed using a dynamic list for all the rows.

The problem is I cannot edit a row or a data cell in that row.

I cannot, for the life of me, find any example on how to update that cell.

My code is standard.

```
rows: myClassList
                              .map(
                            ((element) => DataRow(
                              cells: <DataCell>[
                                DataCell(
                                            Text(element.itemA),) ,
                        
                                    placeholder: false,
                                    showEditIcon: false,
                                    onTap: () {} ),
                                DataCell(Text(element.itemB,),
                                    placeholder: false,
                                    showEditIcon: true,
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print('ontap');
                                    }

                                ),
                              ],
                              selected: true,
                              onSelectChanged: (newValue) {
                                print('row 1 pressed');
                              },

                            )),
                          ).toList(),
                        ),
```

The data-table works.. I just need the user to edit the cells and fill in the values they need.

Am I missing something? Is this the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `DataCell(Text...)` to

```
DataCell(
    TextFormField(
     initialValue: '$value', 
     keyboardType: textType, 
     onFieldSubmitted: (val){
        print('onSubmited $val');
     },
   ),
  showEditIcon: true
),
```

Into

```
onFieldSubmitted: (val){print('onSubmited $key $val');}
```

work with val: update datasource and rebuild widget

Answer (score 2):

Use controller for sorting edit column

```
TextFormField(
    controller: TextEditingController(text: "SomeText"),
    //initialValue: ceilText,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.editableTextInputType,
    onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
    print('onSubmited $val');
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataCell(
          TextFormField(
            initialValue: element.itemB,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.editableTextInputType,
            onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
              setState(() {
               //you can do anything you want
              });
            },
          ),
          showEditIcon: true);
```